# Cross compiling in Lazarus: cannot find fcllaz

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to cross compile a project from x86_64 Linux to Win64 in Lazarus. On build, I get:`Fatal: Cannot find system used by fcllaz of package FCL`.

I've seen this question asked in several places, and I guess I don't understand the answers. I do have fcllaz.pas. I've seen "Check your -Fu" answers, but there isn't enough detail for me to determine what I'm looking for or need to do. I've seen those statements in fpc.cfg, I'm just not sure what to do with them.

I'm quite new to Lazarus. In the form of a question: how do I point Lazarus/fpc to fcllaz and get this thing compiled?

Answer (score 0):

The error is that it can't find unit **system**, fcllaz is just what is being compiled when it first misses system.

Not finding system means the compiler can't find the RTL (and the rest of the precompiled units) for the selected target (win64). These probably don't come with your installation so you have to build and install them yourself.

The -Fu are lines in the fpc.cfg that should point to the relevant units.

Though a bit outdated, the [buildfaq](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf) has a lot of background info how the system builds and finds its units.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm discovering is that I need to compile both freepascal and Lazarus from source instead of trying to use the distribution binaries. Would you agree with that?

Comment: Yes, crosspackages are not prepared, except win32->win64 and win32->wince and some mac variants.